# Find specs on a Macbook

Tags: mac, specifications

I want to sell my Macbook which has had its memory and hard drive upgraded.

Is there a program that I can install on a Mac running OSX and have it display a compilation of the Macbook's hardware specs?

I'm looking for something more detailed than the "About this Mac" option from the Apple icon in the top left corner.

Is my Macbook's "hardware overview" be considered sensitive information?  What info should I *NOT* give out or share from `About this mac->More info`?

Comment: Have you see the "More Info..." button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"System Profiler" under your applications/utilities will give you a breakdown of all the hardware in the computer.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/using-apple-system-profiler-in-mac-os-x.html

Answer (score 2):

Click on "More info" in the "About this Mac" window.

Answer (score 1):

System Profiler application, available in Applications/Utilites and by clicking „More info” button in „About this Mac” window.

Answer (score 1):

You can get same information that the "System Profiler" app (accessible in the Applications/Utilities" folder or by "About This Mac" plus "More info...") gives you from the command line with (surprise):

```
$ system_profiler
```

See `man system_profiler` or `system_profiler -h` for a list of the many, many command line options to limit the display to just what you want to know...

If the command line is your thing, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on my Mac currently, but I believe that there is a System Information application, possibly in the Applications/Utilities folder. It lists out all of the hardware in your Mac including CPU, video card, etc.